# Matlab or R: relationship between categorical vs continuous variable

Tags: r, correlation, matlab

I have a six groups=[1:6] ACTid and a resulting continuous variable observed for each of the members is the group: Y

```
ACTid(1:10)  Y(1:10,:)

ans =

    3.0000   36.8791
    2.0000   71.5823
    6.0000  104.3075
    3.0000   33.4862
    1.0000    1.5298
    5.0000    0.1063
    6.0000  157.3075
    4.0000   11.4117
    2.0000    3.8024
    1.0000   52.3496
```

What's the best way to check the relationship of the groups with the continuous variable?

The Continuous variable is derived from this model:

**UPDATE**

My model is of following multiplicative form:

> Let us simplify notation by allowing the number of germs (cfu)
>   units picked up by nurses'  hands to be called $Y$. **ACTid** determines **n** in, $i=1:n $
>
> \begin{equation} Y_{i}=\displaystyle  \lambda_i V_i A_i-\beta_iY_{i-1} \end{equation}
>
> Where values are sampled via Monte-Carlo sampling for each run for: $h=lognormal~(1.5,0.1)$, $\lambda=\Gamma(15,3)$, $\beta=$empirical non-negative.
>   $A=lognormal~(7,1.9)$ and $V=$empirical non-negative. The choice of these parameters is further dependent on the type of care $ACTid=1:6$;

Comment: Correlation makes no sense if one of your variables is nominal. Do you mean *relationship*?

Comment: Hmm I see. Yes that makes more semantic sense

Comment: @PeterFlom question editted

Comment: What (conditional) characteristics of the continuous variable do you have - is it necessarily positive? Skewed? Is variance related to mean? ...

Comment: @Glen_b I've added some more details to my question. The CV is positive and heavily right skewed. Basically it's a model for predicting how dirty a nurses' hands are after patient care. $ACTid$ is the type of care and hence influences how many surfaces they touch. I would like to investigate the quantitative effect of the care type on the contamination level. Does this make more sense

Comment: You mention $h$ under your model. Where is the $h$ in your model?

Comment: @Glen_b h is the efficacy of a hand-wash after Y is fully calculated ie Y=hY. Ie. h is not sampled at every i, but only once at the end. I'm not sure how to write that in terms of the model.

Comment: How is $h$ used in the data you fit the model to? Are you computing some $Y^* = hY$, or are you fitting to the original $Y$ values?

Comment: I'm not fitting my model to the data, I am using it to produce the data. After the nurse touches n surfaces they have $Y_n$ germs on their hands then they wash their hands (or not) with efficacy h so the final germ count after washing is $hY_n$. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only one independent variable there is no possibility of an interaction.

In `R`, something like this (untested code) should work:

```
m1 <- lm(DV~as.factor(group))
```